# (Python) - Peewee - How to create a foreign key

Tags: python, sql, orm, foreign-key-relationship, peewee

I'm trying to create a relationship between two table fields via a foreign key but failing with the examples in the doc or related threads at stackoverflow. Here's my code:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    """ Field Types """
    user_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    username = CharField(25)
    role = ForeignKeyField(User, to_field='role_id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'


class User(BaseModel):
    """ Field Types """
    role_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    rolename = CharField(25)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'roles'
```

to_field refers to the related field in the equivalent table 'users' in my code snippet. In the docs of peewee I saw related_names as parameter which refers to the non-existing field tweets in the User model.

```
class User(Model):
    name = CharField()

class Tweet(Model):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='tweets')
    content = TextField()
```

Hopefully someone could explain this syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you wanted to have 2 `"User"` models.  And `tweets` has nothing to do with your `User` and `Role` schema.

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but I think something like this should work.

```
class Role(BaseModel):
    """ Field Types """
    role_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    rolename = CharField(25)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'roles'

class User(BaseModel):
    """ Field Types """
    user_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    username = CharField(25)
    role = ForeignKeyField(Role, to_field="role_id")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
```

Hopefully the meaning of `to_field` is clear.  It says, that the `role` field on the `User` model should point to a record in the `Role` table based on the `role_id` column.

Related name is used for the back reference.  For example, you could combine them so that you could access all the users that have a given role.

For example, change your user class:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    """ Field Types """
    user_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    username = CharField(25)
    role = ForeignKeyField(Role, to_field="role_id", related_name="users")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
```

Now given you've got your say, "Superuser" role loaded you should be able to do something like this to loop over all the users that have that role.

```
for user in superuser.users
    print user.username
```

Comment: @user3147268 I've updated my answer with an example of using `related_name`.  It's a little weird because it adds a property to the "other side" of the foreign key relationship.

Comment: I'm sorry for the errors. I created a new, smaller version for stackoverflow. An extended version of your code worked for my project. 

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that the second class User

```
class User(BaseModel):
    """ Field Types """
    role_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    rolename = CharField(25)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'roles'
```

should be class Roles?

```
class Roles(BaseModel):
    """ Field Types """
    role_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    rolename = CharField(25)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'roles'
```